# C++ Atomic fetch_add

Tags: c++, c++11, atomic

This is not a networking question. It's a question about atomics, but the scenario surrounds the context of networking.

I have several threads receiving pieces of a network message. Each is supposed to increment an atomic variable of `TotalBytesReceive` until the `TotalBytes` value has been reached. I'm having an odd behavior with atomics which is probably due to my misunderstanding of something.

Within several threads:

```
size_t BytesReceived = // number of bytes received in this thread
bool IsMessageFinished = msg->IsMsgFinished(BytesReceived);
if(IsMessageFinished) 
     {do something else}
```

The msg object which is shared contains

```
class Msg
{
    std::vector<char> MessageData;          // The data received for the message
    const size_t TotalBytes;                      // The final size of the complete message
    std::atomic<size_t> TotalBytesReceived; // The bytes received so far
    std::mutex m_mutex;                     // Just for testing

public:
    Msg(size_t totalbytes) : TotalBytesReceived(0), TotalBytes(totalbytes) 
    {
        MessageData.resize(TotalBytes);
    }

    bool IsMsgFinished(size_t BytesReceived)
    {
        // std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(m_mutex); // uncommenting fixed the problem
        size_t newtotal = TotalBytesReceived += BytesReceived;

        std::stringstream ss;
        ss << BytesReceived << " received. New total " << newtotal << '\n';
        std::cout << ss.str(); // For diagnostics

        return newtotal == TotalBytes;
    }

    // Other functions for setting MessageData aren't important here
}
```

The big issue is that I when multiple threads call `IsMsgFinished` my diagnostic output is showing that `newtotal` has the same value multiple times. That shouldn't be possible. (`BytesReceived` is never 0) Is there a gross error here?

If I use a mutex and unique_lock in the `IsMsgFinished` function everything works great but I'd like to not use a lock.

Comment: You say `TotalBytes` isn't important but you're relying on that value for your test?

Comment: The lack of `endl` in your diagnostics suggests to me that perhaps this is not the actual code you ran to reach your conclusions. Are you sure there is nothing else interacting with this at all?

Comment: Consider TotalBytes a constant as far as the question is concerned. I actually used a stringstream to build a string before the cout to not interweave the outputs from threads. Let's not be pedantic here. The question is about the atomic not having the expected behavior.

Comment: Then present your [MCVE] because it's entirely unclear on what you're basing your observations.

Comment: @RussellTrahan This is not about pedantry. The code as you posted it does not exhibit the behavior described in the question. https://wandbox.org/permlink/AtzrziRgbPnoE5Re

Comment: Maybe its a difference between being on clang versus VS17. I just tinkered with your link. Can't see a difference in the code.

Comment: @RussellTrahan You should amend your question with a self-contained example like mine (that you have confirmed reproduces the issue in MSVC), and specify that the issue happens under that compiler.

Comment: Looks like a [Readers–writers problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writers_problem) when you should prioritize reader. I.e. [`TotalBytesReceived.fetch_add(BytesReceived, std::memory_order_relaxed)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/fetch_add) and [`return TotalBytes.load(std::memory_order_seq_cst) == TotalBytes`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

Comment: But you'd better have two methods, `bool IsMsgFinished()` and some `notify_chunk_done(std::size_t chunk_size)`. 2. Classic thread synchronization will work much better then an `lock free` alg, if you just need to await since multiple threads download data split in chunks in parallel. I.e. [join](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/join)

Comment: Thanks Victor. I've been unable to reproduce this in a "minimal example" probably because the other unrelated memory/thread activity is causing the issue. I suspected the memory order issue, but don't understand those options well. I think I'm settling on the locking option with a mutex.

Comment: All in all, the behavior has been sporadic which makes it hard to understand the problem. That's why I asked if something looks wrong. Its an intermittent problem which makes it hard to reproduce in a minimal example.